# How many coin flips to get $k$ heads with probability $1-\delta$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

Say we have a coin with a probability of $p$ to get "head" on each toss, and assume that we have a parameter $k\in\mathbb N^+$.

I'm looking for an upper bound on the number of tosses $N$ that would ensure that we see at least $k$ heads with probability $1-\delta$.

I have made an attempt of computing such a bound, but am not sure that it is correct or if it can be simplified.

---

The Chernoff bound tells us that if we mark the number of heads by $H$ then:

$$\Pr[H\le Np(1-\gamma)]\le e^{-\gamma^2Np/2}$$

This means that to get a probability of at most $\delta$ we would need to set
$$
\gamma = \sqrt{\frac{2\ln\delta^{-1}}{Np}}.
$$
This means that the requirement that $H\ge k$ implies that we need
$$
k = Np(1-\gamma) = Np\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{2\ln\delta^{-1}}{Np}}\right)=Np-\sqrt{{2{Np}\ln\delta^{-1}}}.
$$

Denote $x=\sqrt {Np}$, then 
$$
x^2-x\cdot\sqrt{{2\ln\delta^{-1}}} - k = 0.
$$

Then we have 
$$x=\frac{\sqrt{{2\ln\delta^{-1}}}+\sqrt{2\ln\delta^{-1}+4k}}{2}
=\frac{\sqrt{{\ln\delta^{-1}}}+\sqrt{\ln\delta^{-1}+4k}}{\sqrt2}.$$

Therefore:
$$
N = x^2/p = \frac{\left(\sqrt{{\ln\delta^{-1}}}+\sqrt{\ln\delta^{-1}+4k}\right)^2}{2p}
= \frac{{{\ln\delta^{-1}}}+2(\ln\delta^{-1}+\sqrt{4k\ln\delta^{-1}})+{(\ln\delta^{-1}+4k)}}{2p}
= \frac{{{2\ln\delta^{-1}}}+2k+\sqrt{4k\ln\delta^{-1}}}{p}.
$$

---

- **Is my analysis correct? Is there a way to simplify the bound?**

To me, it seems wrong, as I would expect that $N=k/p+O(1)$ would be enough when $\delta$ is constant. What am I missing?

Comment: Could be a lot simpler, really you just want probability of a Binomial(N,p) distribution being at least k to be at most $1-\delta$. You can look at any statistical tables and find this, looking through to find a suitable N

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst - I don't want to look at tables, I need a bound that is a function of $k,p$ and $\delta$. $k,p$ and $\delta$ are parameters and not concrete numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A foolish arithmetic mistake in one of the steps.
The correct bound is $$N=\frac{{{2\ln\delta^{-1}}}+k+\sqrt{2k\ln\delta^{-1}}}{p}$$

Going back to the analysis, we have:

$$x=\frac{\sqrt{{2\ln\delta^{-1}}}+\sqrt{2\ln\delta^{-1}+4k}}{2}
=\frac{\sqrt{{\ln\delta^{-1}}}+\sqrt{\ln\delta^{-1}+\color{red}{2}k}}{\sqrt2}.$$

Therefore:
$$
N = x^2/p = \frac{\left(\sqrt{{\ln\delta^{-1}}}+\sqrt{\ln\delta^{-1}+2k}\right)^2}{2p}
= \frac{{{\ln\delta^{-1}}}+2(\ln\delta^{-1}+\sqrt{2k\ln\delta^{-1}})+{(\ln\delta^{-1}+2k)}}{2p}
= \frac{{{2\ln\delta^{-1}}}+k+\sqrt{2k\ln\delta^{-1}}}{p}.
$$

I'm still wondering if there is a way to simplify this analysis.